# getLayoutParams().height/width

Tags: android, image, layout, size

I am trying to set the size of my image using getLayoutParams().height/width, but the problem is, all my numbers are store in values folder. I know I can just set getLayoutParams().height= 500; but I want to use the numbers in the values.xml instead. Is there any other way to do it? I tried getLayoutParams().height=R.integer.ImageWidth but didn't work.

```
<integer name="ImageWidth">501</integer>
<integer name="ImageHeight">200</integer>
```

Comment: are you trying to GET the image size or SET the image size?

Comment: I am trying to GET the image size from my values.xml

Comment: so you have different sized images with their dims stored in xml?

Comment: ok, posted an answer that might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, haven't tried this myself, but this might work.

```
Resources res = getResources();
int imageWidth = res.getInteger(R.values.ImageWidth);
int imageHeigth = res.getInteger(R.values.ImageHeigth);
```

Comment: and it's stored like in this link?  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer

Comment: using the <resources> </resources>?

Comment: weird, are you sure the problem is with getting the resources? add 2 textviews and use tvOne.setText(imageWidth) and tvTwo.setText(imageHeigth) to see if you're  pulling the values from xml

Comment: This works great!, I double checked my code, and I noticed that I missed something. Thanks for all your help.!